# How should I choose a graphics card that's right for my needs?

Tags: graphics, nvidia, amd

I'm developing my own game using Ogre3D, and I'm want to implement things like SSAO, dynamic shadows, AI, physics, etc...and I know my current card is barely gonna be able to handle it.

So my question is, how do I find out what I'll need in a graphics card to support the features I want to implement?

Comment: Your question is far too localized for this site. Not only is it localized for your needs, it's localized in time, where any answers to this question will quickly be out of date. Please see the [FAQ] about what types of questions to ask here.

Comment: Yeah I kinda figured that....sorry about that! :) I'll choose Seth's answer, though. :)

Comment: I think this question could be generalized to be useful...but yes, it's not right now.  Picking hardware for development is a reasonable question.

Comment: @SethBattin OK, I generalized the question. Perhaps you can similarly generalize your answer?

Comment: @Byte56 not very well...but I tried.

Answer (score 1):

Say, for the sake of example, that you were pondering your GT8500 and whether you need to replace it.  Here is the only relevant part of [your card's spec](http://www.nvidia.com/object/geforce_8500_tech_specs.html):

> API Support
>
> - Complete DirectX support, including Microsoft DirectX 10 Shader Model 4.0
> - Full OpenGL® support, including OpenGL 2.0

If you intend to use features beyond these in your game, you need a new card.  But you might want to keep the old hardware handy for testing purposes.